# Yii findAllByPk without ordering

Tags: php, yii

I have an array of Ids which has already been ordered based on some criterias
Example:

```
$array = array(5,4,10,3,1);
```

and i am using yii to get all these records from database:

```
$records = TableName::model()->findAllByPk($array);
```

this is returning me the correct results but its being sorted by the primary key in ascending order.

i even tried using CDbCriteria like this:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition('primaryKeyColumnName',$array);

$records = TableName::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

and its still being sorted.. can anyone help me plz

Comment: you should order like you did, after finding your records

Comment: `$criteria->order = 'FIELD(id,5,4,10,3,1)'`, but I'd order them after finding (as tinyByte suggested)

Answer (score 0):

Add This line and try I think It will work as you want.

```
$criteria->order = "FIELD(id, '5,4,10,3,1')";
```